# I cant understand why when app crase and I get this message…?

Tags: ios

warning: error on line 2184 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1708/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "void macosx_kill_inferior_safe()": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282063/handling-hidden-errors-objective-c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the debugger crashing , not your app. There is no problem with the app. 
May be you are out of memory.
Update your debugger tool may help you.